# What happens to logs generated by logger if there is no logging daemon installed or active

Tags: linux, rsyslog

If you have a Linux distribution either without a logging daemon installed, or with the logging daemon disabled, what happens to the logs generated by the `logger` command?

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 with the rsyslog service. When I turn this service off, I can still use the `logger` command, nothing gets written to the syslog, but the command still accepts my input and has a zero exit code.

When there is no logging service, what happens to logs generated by `logger`?

How can the `logger` command work without somewhere to send the logs? Why does `logger` exit successfully if there was nothing to receive the logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'logger' sends data to the Unix socket `/dev/log`. (It's a socket despite being in /dev.)

On most Linux distributions, this socket is *not* owned by a traditional syslog daemon anymore – its other end does not actually go to rsyslog directly. Rather, the /dev/log socket is owned by the *systemd-journald* service, which is still running and receiving messages.

```
# fuser -v /dev/log
                                 USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log:    root          1 F.... systemd
                                 root        304 F.... systemd-journal
```

*(Note that init also holds the socket – if journald is stopped, but there is some activity on the socket, init will automatically start the service again… much like 'inetd' did in the past for TCP services.)*

Systemd-journald stores logs in /var/log/journal, which you can read using `journalctl -f` instead of the usual 'tail -f' (they're in indexed binary format). Normally, messages via /dev/log will continue to be written there even when rsyslogd is down.

```
$ logger Hello

$ journalctl -n 1
Jul 12 18:12:26 ember root[951422]: Hello
```

In such systems, the rsyslogd and syslog-ng packages only receive *relayed* messages from systemd-journald, not directly from programs. They work either by listening at a different socket (inside /run/systemd), to which journald forwards all messages – or by directly reading the binary log files from /var/log/journal.

(Usually the direct .journal file access is preferred as it allows rsyslogd to collect additional fields included by programs, which would otherwise be lost when using the socket-based message forwarding.)

If you point 'logger' at a Unix socket which is not accepting messages, it will in fact show an error message like it should:

```
$ python -c "from socket import *; socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM).bind('/tmp/log')"

$ logger -u /tmp/log Hello
logger: socket /tmp/log: Connection refused
```